# How to use button as form control in Angular?

Tags: angular

I use base form controls for input, autocomplete, etc. fields as shown below:

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="{{controlName}}"/>
</div>
```

and now I need to add button to the form as shown below:

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'button'">
    <button mat-button formControlName="{{controlName}}" (click)="create()">Create</button>
</div>
```

But I encounter "*No value accessor for form control with name: createEmp*" error (`createEmp` is the `controlName` value that I pass from component). So, is it possible to fix this error?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement custom reactive form control for your button with implement the ControlValueAccessor interface.
See this article for your reference:[link](https://medium.com/@kevinmerckx/creating-a-custom-angular-form-control-43dfc4b654c0)

```
export class TagsComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange: (value: string[]) => void = () => {};
  onTouched: Function = () => {};
  isDisabled = false;
  
  …
  
  writeValue(value: string[]) {
    this.tags = value || [];
  }
  
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  
  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    this.isDisabled = disabled;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks. I will implement it later, but I am wondering can I use this without creating  custom reactive form control (at least for now). Then I will implement it later.

Comment: I think there is no other way to handler it. Since you can't bind formcontrolname to a 'none user input' html element. Reactive forms is used to handler user inputs, and button is not the case..

Answer (score 4):

Fredrick, a button doesn't accept a FormControl, but remember always: a FormControl exists even if there is no "input" in .html. So, you can do, e.g. (imagine you are defining a formGroup called "form")

```
<button mat-button [disabled]="form.get(controlName).disabled"
                   (click)="form.get(controlName).setValue("one");
                            form.get(controlName).markAsTouched()">
   Create
</button>
```

Or, as Kevin Zang said, create a custom FormControl